# Looking up unknown duplicate values and returning value in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I am looking for a way to identify parts that get ordered multiple times and then determine which parts get ordered the most. For an example if I had a list like this;

Apples

Bread

Pear

Grape

Apple

Apple

Pear

I would like my table to show that Apples appears the most and then Pears. The thing that gets me stuck is that I don't want to search by Apples because I don't know that it's duplicated. I've been playing with INDEX and MATCH but not knowing what your looking for as duplicated has me stumped. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be a Pivot Table, but here is a little macro:

```
Sub SuperSimpleFrequencyTable()
    Dim C As Range, A As Range, B As Range

    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set B = Range("B:B")

    A.Copy B
    B.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set C = B.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 1)

    With C
        .Formula = "=countif(A:A,B1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Each item appears in column **B** and next  to it, the count of the number of times that item occurs in column **A**